# Call gradlew from Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration, gradlew

My project contains a gradlew shell script and a Jenkinsfile in the root. The Jenkinsfile contains:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
node('jnlp-slave-with-java-build-tools') {
    sh 'gradlew build -x check'
}
```

When I push this to my respository, Jenkins finds the Jenkinsfile and tries to run gradlew. It fails, however, informing me that:

```
Running on ECS-2d51eb80546b7 in /home/jenkins/workspace/tems_chore_add-jenkins-file-7VBJJMGP4JS3QPUSNL2ROWDE3ECV5A4EJQJ6Z5VCSPDK7UABIPVQ
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[tems_chore_add-jenkins-file-7VBJJMGP4JS3QPUSNL2ROWDE3ECV5A4EJQJ6Z5VCSPDK7UABIPVQ] Running shell script
+ gradlew build -x check
/home/jenkins/workspace/tems_chore_add-jenkins-file-7VBJJMGP4JS3QPUSNL2ROWDE3ECV5A4EJQJ6Z5VCSPDK7UABIPVQ@tmp/durable-838b5837/script.sh: 2: /home/jenkins/workspace/tems_chore_add-jenkins-file-7VBJJMGP4JS3QPUSNL2ROWDE3ECV5A4EJQJ6Z5VCSPDK7UABIPVQ@tmp/durable-838b5837/script.sh: gradlew: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I modify my Jenkinsfile so that the gradlew script is located and run correctly?

## Followup #1

The following:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
node('jnlp-slave-with-java-build-tools') {
    sh './gradlew build -x check'
}
```

Results in:

```
tems_chore_add-jenkins-file-7VBJJMGP4JS3QPUSNL2ROWDE3ECV5A4EJQJ6Z5VCSPDK7UABIPVQ] Running shell script
+ ./gradlew build -x check
/home/jenkins/workspace/tems_chore_add-jenkins-file-7VBJJMGP4JS3QPUSNL2ROWDE3ECV5A4EJQJ6Z5VCSPDK7UABIPVQ@tmp/durable-3c901cf0/script.sh: 2: /home/jenkins/workspace/tems_chore_add-jenkins-file-7VBJJMGP4JS3QPUSNL2ROWDE3ECV5A4EJQJ6Z5VCSPDK7UABIPVQ@tmp/durable-3c901cf0/script.sh: ./gradlew: not found
```

So still getting a 'not found' error.

## Followup #2

Running:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
node('jnlp-slave-with-java-build-tools') {
    files = sh (script: 'ls -l',
                returnStdout: true).trim()
    echo "${files}"

    sh './gradlew build -x check'
}
```

Outputs `total 0`, suggesting that perhaps I'm in the wrong, directory or have a permissions issue? Suggestions would be welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out be a misunderstanding on my part: I'd presumed that Jenkins would pull down the repo *before* it ran my Jenkinsfile, but this isn't exactly the case, and I needed to do it myself by adding:

```
checkout scm
```

I'm now receiving an unrelated error.

This is covered in the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/), but I was under the false impression that it woulnd't be necessary in my setup.